# How to get custom local storage value in magento2?

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2

How to get custom local storage value in magento2?

I need to get the custom local storage value in php file .

How to do that

Thanks.

Comment: store value in session than use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom local storage are stored at client side means in user's browser , you can not access it directly. You need to use ajax call with that info to your server to get into in php file.